# Caching in General and in MVC in Particular

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache

I need some clarification about the way caching works.

**I've a specific question:**

I've a main page (index) within that page I have a lot of static element (headlines, texs and etc'), one more thing that I have in that page is a drop down list that initialize when the DOM fully loaded, let me zoom in a little bit so you could catch my drift :

My Index page is loaded, after the page is loaded I send request in AJAX (with Jquery) that get the "Options" for the drop down list from the DB(SQL Azure), I did it in order to display the page to the user first then get the data ( so the user wont wait that extra second to the page to load) from the DB.

Now **when I cache that page, do I cache also the request of the drop down list ?**

You wanna see some code ? sure.

I'm working with MVC architectural design, so my code looks like this :

**Home Controller:**

```
 // The Action that display the Index page
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration=60*60)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

 // The Action that get the data from the DB.
    [OutputCache(Duration=15)]
    public JsonResult GetProfiles()
    {
         Dictionary<string, string> ProfileDictionary  = DataQueries.GetUserProfiles();

         return Json(ProfileDictionary);
    }
```

**Part of the Index page:**

```
 <div class="gap-bottom" >
    <h2><span class="font-Droid">Step 2: </span><span class="font-Crete">Select Profile</span></h2>
    <p>Pick a profile....</p>
    @Html.DropDownList("filterSelect", new MultiSelectList(new[] { "Choose Profile" }), new { @style = "width: 50%", @class = "form-control" })

</div>
```

**Script of the Index page**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetProfiles',

            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                    $('#filterSelect').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));

                });

            },
            error: function (ts) {
                if (ts.readyState == 0 || ts.status == 0) return;
                alert(ts.responseText)
            }

        });
```

**So my question is:**

If I cache the page does the drop down list is also cached ? or I need to cache the Action in spsfic like I did ?

**Bottom line**, I want to cache the page for long period(like hour) and the drop down list for 10 second.

I did some testing myself (with the network tab in the page inspector of Google chrome) and for the index page I see sometime "200 OK" and sometime "304 not modified", the ratio its 1:1 one time 200 ok and sometime 304 not modified when i refresh the page.

Regarding the drop down list, I get always 200 OK from /Home/GetProfiles, as I see it, this action are not cache at all.

When I look on the header (in the network tab in Google chrome) i see for the two request (localhost - get index page, Home/GetProfiles - POST get profiles)

> Cache-Control:max-age=0

And in the respond header is see:

LocalHost:

> Cache-Control:public, max-age=3427

GetProfiles:

> Cache-Control:public, max-age=20

This is what I'm want to be there(in the headers of the requests and respond) ? and if its possible to cache only the page for X second and the request with AJAX for Y second ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request will always hit the server, because you are using a POST request. Change it to GET to see the difference.

[RFC 2616 in section 9.1 (POST)] http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1